# Setting JAVA_HOME error

Tags: windows, java

I need to set JAVA_HOME in order to use a game engine in eclipse. I set the JAVA_HOME to the bin file location where java is installed on my computer. I also set the path location in the system variables. When I echo %JAVA_HOME% in the command prompt, the prompt returns the bin file location where java is installed. However, when I enter the command: java -version or javac -version the prompt returns an error message, saying that java or javac is unknown.

Comment: Can you share your `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` env variables?

Answer (score 0):

After setting the JAVA_HOME, you have to set the JAVA_HOME into the path. On linux:

```bsh
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```